# Datas in tableviewcell are repeating

Tags: ios, uitableview, reuseidentifier

```
REFeveItinerarioCell *cell = nil;
         cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSDictionary *itemData = [self.tableDatawithcoordinate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        if(cell==nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"New Cell");

            NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"REFeveItinerarioCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];

 //my code for filling tableview           
}
```

Hi All,
Like above ,Im filling the tableview. But after some values the same values are repeating.What can be the problem??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should register the nib with the tableview, probably in `viewDidLoad:` like this:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"REFeveItinerarioCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
```

You should then be doing this in your cellForRow method:

```
/**
 *  Asks the data source for a cell to insert in a particular location of the table view.
 *
 *  @param  tableView                   A table-view object requesting the cell.
 *  @param  indexPath                   An index path locating a row in tableView.
 *
 *  @return An object inheriting from UITableViewCell that the table view can use for the specified row.
 */
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell               = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //  do any of the configuration

    return cell;
}
```

The reason why the data will be the same for certain cells is because the UITableViewCells are being reused. That means that a previous cell and it's properties are being reused for a new cell. You should nil out and set any properties you do not want to be the same.

Comment: @Ranju I have change like this the data is ok. But while im scrolling one of my data in tableview is changing as zero(0)??